# Dynamic Horizontal Axis Crossing Excel Bubble Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm attempting to make a 4 quadrant bubble chart in Excel to compare some competitor companies. I've input all my data from a pivot table, with 4 slicers to filter what the bubble chart is showing you.

[image: Example]

I have set the max value on the y-axis to 2100, with the x-axis crossing it at its midpoint. Unfortunately, when I change the filters, the y-axis needs to change as well, but I'm unsure how to get my y axis crossing point to change to the midpoint of the new value.

[image: Example 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably can't do this with built-in axis, but could create an "artificial axis" made from calculated points that adjust with your sliced data.

Comment: Is there any value more than 2100 you have set for the Scale ?

Comment: No, 2100 is my max value